# Does BigQuery and Hadoop connector work for federated tables?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, google-bigquery, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm following the example on:
https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/examples/bigquery-connector-spark-example

I have a federated table on BigQuery. Would this be able to pull data from it?

Answer (score 2):

The BigQuery connector doesn't currently have special logic for handling federated tables, so won't work correctly in that it would try to "export" to another GCS location. I've filed a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigdata-interop/issues/32) to track this feature; in the meantime, if the federated data is indeed already in GCS, you should still be able to access it directly as a normal FileInputFormat (or sc.textFile), you just lose the schema/metadata benefits of going through BigQuery.